# Serving static file with Go gives an 404 error

Tags: go

### Task:

I try to serve a static file with Golang.

### Problem:

The directory content is shown, but the file in the directory is not found.

### Project structure:

```
projectdir/

  |- main.go
  |- static/
    |- main.css
  |- templates
    |- index.tmpl
```

### Source snippets:

main.go

```
func serv() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))

srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:      r,
    Addr:         "127.0.0.1:8666",
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
}
```

### Problem description

If I start the program and point my browser to 127.0.0.1:8666/static/, the content of the directory *./static* is listed, i.e. *main.css*

If I click the file *main.css*, the server response is 404.

### Question

What do I miss?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gorilla router differs from Go's, in that Gorilla will only match the exact URL given, and not just the URL prefix. This is explained in more detail in the [Gorilla documentation](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#static-files), where it explains how [`PathPrefix`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.PathPrefix) can be used for serving files:

```
r.PathPrefix("/static/").
    Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
```