# Serving static files using golang embed

Tags: go, templates, embed

I have looked around and cannot find a solution for what I have in hands at the moment.

I have a go project I am setting up (deployed into a docker image) and I have some HTML templating that needs to be done. The templating part works well using the embed declaration, however the same does not seem to work for the files that the HTML requires, *e.g.*, css files.

Here is a simple example I have setup in order to try to play with embed and see what is going wrong, but no luck.

Project directory

```
|
|- main.go
\- templates
  |- page.html
  \- static
    |- style.css
    \- stylesheets
      \- style.css (preferred location)
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "net/http"
    "simple-server/handlers"
)

//go:embed templates
var templatesFs embed.FS

//go:embed templates/static
var staticFiles embed.FS

func main() {
    http.Handle("/hello", handlers.HelloHandler{
        TemplatesFs: templatesFs,
    })

    http.Handle(
        "/static/",
        // the following works
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./templates")),
        // the following does not work
        //http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFiles))),
    )

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8001", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

hello.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type HelloHandler struct {
    TemplatesFs embed.FS
}

func (h HelloHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFS(h.TemplatesFs, "templates/page.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to parse the template: %s", err)

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to execute the template: %s", err)

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>Session {{ .Number }}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">Page HTML template</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.text {
    color: #0088ff;
}
```

As per the comment on the `main.go` file, if the file is served through `http.Dir`, it works. But this is going to be served through a docker file, so I need the `http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFiles))`, however in doing so, the `style.css` file always returns a 404.

Am I missing something? What is it?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably taking relative path corresponding to where is it created and NOT the root of your embedded filesystem. So I feel the issue is at `http.FS(staticFiles)`

May be you can first create a fileSystem rooted at `templates/static`, like following

```golang
staticFs, err := fs.Sub(staticFiles, "templates/static")
// Handle the err
```

and then do

```golang
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(staticFs))))
```

Let me know if it works or not!

Comment: Thank you, this does solve the issue. I had further issues which were related to the fact I was using Gorilla Mux on my project and that was the crux of it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448046) which I only found today allowed me to solve all my problems. Marking this as the accepted answer since I was unaware the example I did at the time was not reflecting the entirety of my setup and it's not your fault.